# Creating Reachability Analyzer paths using Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

As part of my AWS deployment, I would like to deploy a set of paths into the Reachability Analyzer that I can use to diagnose connectivity problems in my application.

Does anyone know if this is possible using Terraform? I cannot find any examples so am presuming not at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not yet supported, but there is already a github issue on that for aws provider:

- [VPC Reachability Analyzer / EC2 Network Insights](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16715)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently supported via the [aws_ec2_network_insights_path](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_network_insights_path) and [aws_ec2_network_insights_analysis](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_network_insights_analysis) resources in the AWS Provider.

example from the docs:

```
resource "aws_ec2_network_insights_path" "path" {
  source      = aws_network_interface.source.id
  destination = aws_network_interface.destination.id
  protocol    = "tcp"
}

resource "aws_ec2_network_insights_analysis" "analysis" {
  network_insights_path_id = aws_ec2_network_insights_path.path.id
}
```